# pip is error,TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python-2.7, pip

#### system

- centos 7.2
- Python 2.7.5

#### install

I install [webhook](https://github.com/NetEaseGame/git-webhook)

```
pip install webhook
### but hava error,then
yum install python-devel -y
## go on,pip doesn't workding
pip
```

#### error

Enter the command contain pip.Then

```
[root@location src]# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
import packaging.requirements
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So,what should I do?!

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall at least pip and maybe python?  It looks like something didn't get installed correctly.

Comment: Same thing happened to me as of this morning on OS X.  I upgraded some packages with pip and now I get this error in the packaging module. It appears that it's severely damaged my python install.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Please see the [solution lower in this thread by Pedro Werneck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035091/241025) instead of this one. It's the correct way to solve the problem.

---

**Preface: I do not recommend this!**

This seems to work, but I have no idea what the consequences could be. This is cargo cult programming at its best! I'm only adding it here in case it can help someone in a bind.

I made changes to the file `requirements.py` where the error occurred.  For @hysg, that would be this file:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py
```

On me on OS X, it's here:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py
```

I modified the the offending line by removing the parentheses for the call to MARKER_EXPR, as demonstrated below:

```
#MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR)("marker")
```

And that worked.

Again, **please be careful!** I don't know what I'm doing and this could potentially cause more harm than good.

Comment: Your answer is solution to me.But I want to know the better solution.

Comment: thanks! also definitely interested in the proper fix for this. e.g. upgrading what package to which version

Comment: I am not a sys admin hence I can't edit that file. Actually, that is why I am I am installing pip using curl.

Answer (score 71):

I had the same problem on a fresh virtualenv and apparently this is a conflict between the version requirements for packaging, pip and pyparsing with the new setuptools. What worked for me was to pin down the old one.

```
pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```

**Update:**

As another answer pointed out, pip has already fixed the bug, so you should try upgrading it instead of using the workaround above.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

Comment: Works for me. I think this answer is better than the accepted one.

Comment: I agree this is better than the accepted answer as you are not modifying files and it can easily be repeated or undone.

Comment: But `pip` is broken with the mentioned stacktrace. Therefore, we can't even run this command to fix it.

Comment: @Tanin I did, and apparently 40+ other people did it, so you might have another issue.

Comment: From what OP wrote, it failed when running the command `pip` (with on arguments); It shouldn't be possible that `pip install ...` would work. I think `python -m pip ...` might work better since it doesn't use `/usr/bin/pip`.

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, running the pip upgrade did not fix the problem; I had to pin setuptools to 33.1.1 as described here.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. worked on CentOS 7.4, Python 2.7.5 when installing certbot

Answer (score 23):

this is work well：

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip 
pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```

Comment: please add some more description what it does and why it solves the problem.

Comment: The second command (pip install setuptools==33.1.1) is what really brings back pip.

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked for me:

```
pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```

It downgraded setuptools from 35.0.1 to 33.1.1 and pyparsing 1.5.7 installed!

Comment: Yes,  just simply need one line command and problem solved. I think this must be the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

Use the following command to upgrade pip, which has the bug fixed:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

It worked for me (centos 7, python 2.7).

For more details: [GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/26900)

Answer (score 10):

I applied the fix

pip install setuptools==33.1.1

and it solved the problem for OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem on a new virtualenv trying to install. I'm running python 2.7.11 and found the two commands belows solve the versioning problem with setuptools:

This forces a pip upgrade, which has a fix for the bug, but doesn't reinstall setup tools, so I was still running on setuptools version 35.0.1

`python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip`

This sets setuptools to an older version.

`pip install setuptools==33.1.1`

After this, I successfully installed my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had a problem that OS/system which means root, not sudo, has been the owner of the pip2 package. But after I had executed this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

it worked like a charm.
Noting, of course that I have a debian distribution.

And then I used what Pedro suggested:

```
sudo pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other uninstall/reinstall/force answers worked for me, but on OS X 10.10.5 with the system Python 2.7.10, I was able to do:

```
pip uninstall packaging pip
easy_install pip # this installed pip 1.4.1
pip install --upgrade pip # and this upgraded to the current pip
```

and I was then able to `import pkg_resources` without a problem.

Should really learn to stop messing with the system Python…

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me too (centos 7, python 2.7).

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip 
pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```