# jupyter notebook setup failed with “TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)”

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed jupiter with pip and run

```
jupyter notebook
```

Then I got this mistakes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1136, in initialize
    super(NotebookApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 243, in initialize
    self.migrate_config()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 162, in migrate_config
    from .migrate import get_ipython_dir, migrate
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/migrate.py", line 35, in <module>
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 93, in <module>
    class TerminalInteractiveShell(InteractiveShell):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 138, in TerminalInteractiveShell
    highlighting: \n %s""" % ', '.join(get_all_styles())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygments/styles/__init__.py", line 79, in get_all_styles
    for name, _ in find_plugin_styles():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygments/plugin.py", line 62, in find_plugin_styles
    for entrypoint in iter_entry_points(STYLE_ENTRY_POINT):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygments/plugin.py", line 45, in iter_entry_points
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Anyone know how to fix it?
I have searched it on google, but nothing is helpful on this particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem but only in one of the two virtualenv on my machine. I had latest pip and same version of jupyter in both environments running on Python-2.7.9

Upon searching more, I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029545/pip-is-error-typeerror-call-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given) which suggested using a specific version of setuptools

```
pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```

My setuptools version was setuptools-34.2.0 earlier.

Answer (score 0):

At first I use python 2.7.10 , which will call the mistake. After change the version of python to 2.7.13 and reinstall jupyter, the problem is fixed:)

May be is easy, but really helpful!