# Ambari HDP 2.4 Add Hosts Metrics Monitor fail to Install

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to add some more hosts to my Ambari Cluster, running HDP 2.4 and the Metrics Monitor does not seem to be installing correctly, all the other services are starting fine.

Below is the output I get when I attempt to start Metrics Monitor on one of the new hosts.

```
255. Building psutil...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Extension
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.7
Checking for previously running Metric Monitor...
Starting ambari-metrics-monitor
Verifying ambari-metrics-monitor process status...
ERROR: ambari-metrics-monitor start failed. For more details, see /var/log/ambari-metrics-monitor/ambari-metrics-monitor.out:
====================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    from core.controller import Controller
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/controller.py", line 28, in <module>
    from metric_collector import MetricsCollector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/metric_collector.py", line 23, in <module>
    from host_info import HostInfo
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/host_info.py", line 22, in <module>
    import psutil
ImportError: No module named psutil
====================
Monitor out at: /var/log/ambari-metrics-monitor/ambari-metrics-monitor.out
```

And this is the output of `/var/log/ambari-metrics-monitor/ambari-metrics-monitor.out`

```
psutil binaries need to be built by running, psutil/build.py manually or by running a, mvn clean package, command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    from core.controller import Controller
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/controller.py", line 28, in <module>
    from metric_collector import MetricsCollector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/metric_collector.py", line 23, in <module>
    from host_info import HostInfo
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_monitoring/core/host_info.py", line 22, in <module>
    import psutil
ImportError: No module named psutil
```

I have tried going into that directory and running `sudo python psutil/build.py`, as well as running `sudo make`. Both do not work.

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your python environment, it's been corrupted somehow (most likely using `sudo pip install <package>`, using sudo and pip together can sometimes cause this issue). There are details on how to fix this issue on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029545/pip-is-error-typeerror-call-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given). After you fix your python issue you should be able to retry the host addition through Ambari.