# TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) in CentOS for Installing pip

Tags: python, linux, centos, pip

Not being an administrator on my lab machine, I tried to install the pip using curl like below in CentOS:

```
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 119, in bootstrap
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.install import install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from setuptools.command import install_scripts
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$
```

Why is it this happening and how to fix it?

Some sys info:

```
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ python 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
Release:    7.4.1708
Codename:   Core
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ivcgpu1.bu.edu 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

UPDATE1: I am not a sudoer hence I can't edit the file mentioned in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031999/2414957
UPDATE2: I am getting this error for other things like below example:

```
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ git clone https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image.git
Cloning into 'scikit-image'...
remote: Counting objects: 54661, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
remote: Total 54661 (delta 31), reused 35 (delta 18), pack-reused 54608
Receiving objects: 100% (54661/54661), 48.24 MiB | 56.99 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (39918/39918), done.
Checking out files: 100% (735/735), done.
[jalal@ivcgpu1 ~]$ cd scikit-image
[jalal@ivcgpu1 scikit-image]$ python setup.py develop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.install import install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from setuptools.command import install_scripts
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[jalal@ivcgpu1 scikit-image]$
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031999/5919344

Comment: Why are you installing pip using curl instead of using anaconda or virtualenv? I am curious because pip does not live in a vacuum. It is generally tied to an interpreter and requires a whole bunch of config that normally requires admin access. Did you first install an interpreter that you have full rights to?